# How to get a string from a Double with a fixed number of decimals?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I have a featureclass (in a File Geodatabase), with a particular field of type Double. I want to copy it over to a text field, so that only 3 decimal places are shown.

For example: `34.78902345 becomes 34.789`

I have gone through this question: [How to convert a double field to a string?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9840/how-to-convert-a-double-field-to-a-string), but that does not solve my issue. I have even tried to format the double field, but even then the text field contains all the decimals.

How do I do this in ArcGIS 10.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use string formatting:

`'{0:.3f}'.format(your_floating_point_value)`

Example:

```
>>> '{0:.3f}'.format(34.78902345)
'34.789'
```

Here is the [Python string formatting cookbook](http://mkaz.com/solog/python-string-format) for reference.

To use this in the field calculator you can create a function:

```
def my_format(val):
  return '{0:.3f}'.format(val)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this python function within Field Calculator:

```
def updateValue(value):
  if value <> '':
    newValue = str(value)
    splitBefore = newValue.split('.')[0]
    splitAfter = newValue.split('.')[1]
    return splitBefore + '.' + splitAfter[:3]
  else: return ''
```

Name =

```
updateValue( !yourFieldName!)
```